# Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^ke^{\frac{2k\pi i}{4n-2}}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n$, when
$$S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^ke^{\frac{2k\pi i}{4n-2}}.$$
I wrote
$$S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\big(-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{4n-2}}\big)^k$$
$$=-e^{\frac{ 2\pi i}{4n-2}}\frac{1-{(-e^\frac{2\pi i}{4n-2}})^n} {1+e^\frac{2\pi i}{4n-2}}.$$
Now $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n$ doesn't exist? Because of we don't know $n$ is even or odd. The answer of the limit of the real part equals to $-\frac{1}{2}$?

Note: $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess you are missing one $-e^\frac{2\pi i}{4n-2}$ in the numerator at the end. Also, try the trigonometric form of that complex number, this may help

Comment: @oliver diaz You mistyped the denominator of the fraction. Also, you miscalculated the limit value. There is $n$ in the numerator.

Comment: I mean this fraction: $e^\frac{2\pi i n}{n-2}$. In the question, this fraction is:  $e^\frac{2\pi i n}{4n-2}$. So $1-{(-e^\frac{2\pi i n}{4n-2})}^n\rightarrow 1-i$, if $n$ is even. Otherwise, $1-{(-e^\frac{2\pi i n}{4n-2})}^n\rightarrow 1+i$.

Comment: @Nmath: I missed the factor $4$. In any event, there is not term $(-e^{2\pi in/(4n-2)})^n$ in your expression.

Comment: @Nmath: I just corrected the information in my previous comments. Notice that
$$ e^{\tfrac{2\pi in}{4n-2}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\tfrac{\pi i}{2}}=i$$
Along the subsequence of even numbers
$$S_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}-\frac{1-i}{2}$$
Along the subsequence if odd numbers
$$S_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}-\frac{1+i}{2}$$

Comment: This is a mistyped, an extra $n$. Your answer is as same as mine.